# How to focus the next cell while clicking tab key and cell coloring

Tags: vb6, msflexgrid

I am new to vb

Flexgrid

```
Header 01 .... 31
Values .........
```

I am entering the values at run time in flexgrid cell, if i click tab button, the focus will move to next cell on the same row.

Code for Ascii

```
Private Sub flexgrid_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
Select Case KeyAscii
  Case 48 To 57
   flexgrid.Text = flexgrid.Text & Chr(KeyAscii)
  Case 46 'Dot
   flexgrid.Text = flexgrid.Text & Chr(KeyAscii)
  Case 8
   If Len(flexgrid.Text) > 0 Then
    flexgrid.Text = Left(flexgrid.Text, (Len(flexgrid.Text) - 1))
   End If
  Case Else
   KeyAscii = 0
   Beep
 End Select
End Sub
```

How to do this.

And also how to change the particular cell background color.
Code

```
    For i = 1 To flexgrid.Rows - 1
        flexgrid.TextMatrix(i, 33) = vbred 'It's giving value like '255'
        flexgrid.TextMatrix(i, 33) = .CellBackColor = vbred 'It's giving value 'False'
    Next i
```

Any ideas & suggestion...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move the selected column use the KeyDown (or KeyUp if you prefer) event and place your code there.

```
Private Sub MSFlexGrid1_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

    If KeyCode = Asc(vbTab) Then
        If MSFlexGrid1.Col < MSFlexGrid1.Cols - 1 Then
            MSFlexGrid1.Col = MSFlexGrid1.Col + 1
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

To change the cell background color first set the cell, then set the CellBackColor.

```
flexgrid.Row = i
flexgrid.Col = 33
flexgrid.CellBackColor = vbRed
```